# Pivotal Cloud Foundry login issue

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I have a PWS account and after installing Cloud Foundry command line interface (CLI),  I tried login from windows command prompt, CYGWIN terminal and Gitbash.
In all the above cases, I cannot login by **`cf login`**

But I am able to login if i issue the command:
**`cf auth email password`**
But the problem with this command is that I am exposing my password on the command line.

**Question**: I would like to know how users of Cloud Foundry Command Line Interface, login to the PWS.

---

*Update 04/29:*  Sharing what i see while trying `cf login` in `Cygwin` and `Gitbash`. Both gives the same type of error response.
*Note that I don't want to put -p password as plaintext in command line unless I am asked explicitly.*

```
mypc /d/spiderman
$ cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Email> myemail@gmail.com
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.


API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.80.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
FAILED
Unable to authenticate.
```

*It's not even asking for password, and responding that unable to authenticate!*

In windows command prompt:

```
D:\spiderman>cf login
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Email> myemail@gmail.com

Password>  [I gave correct password]
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again
```

.

@Kumaresh Babu
I tried what you suggested and still unable to authenticate [Tried in cygwin]

```
mypc /d/spiderman
$ cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io --skip-ssl-validation -o my-org -s development API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Email> myemail@gmail.com
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.

API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.80.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
FAILED
Unable to authenticate.
```

@Kumaresh Babu

I tried the same command in windows command prompt **and it worked, I am able to login.**

```
cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io --skip-ssl-validation -o my-org -s development
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Email> myemail@gmail.com

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted org my-org

Targeted space development



API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.80.0)
User:           myemail@gmail.com
Org:            my-org
Space:          development
```

Comment: cf login -a [api-endpoint] will login interactive mode. What is the issue you are facing with Cygwin and GitBash... ??? Normally developers use cf login -a [api-endpoint] and automation scripts use cf login [-a api-endpoint] [-u username] [-p password] [-o org] [-s space]

Comment: Thank you @PraneethRamesh for offering help.. I updated my post with the error response after my attempts to login from Cygwin and Gitbash. The command that Kumaresh shared below helped to login from windows terminal, but unable to login from Cygwin and Gitbash

Comment: @spiderman Have you tried with "winpty cf login"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io --skip-ssl-validation -o <Org_Name> -s <Space_Name>
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help.. I updated my post after trying your suggestion. Still, unable to authenticate, and it's not prompting for password. I tried in Cygwin.

Comment: I tried the same command in windows command prompt and it worked, I am able to login. Accepted as answer, +1, but do you know why the same command didn't work in Cygwin and Gitbash whereas it worked in windows terminal??

Comment: Please see my reply for the workaround, here is the official issue on CloudFoundry: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in Gitbash by calling `cf login` using `winpty`:

```
winpty cf login
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to expose your password to command line.you can use sso validation.
cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io -sso
this will give you passcode with that you can do login.
make sure you must login first, using your email in the browser.