# "Authenticating... Credentials were rejected, please try again" in Git Bash

Tags: pcf, pcfdev

I already followed URLs like

1. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/171
2. [Pivotal Cloud Foundry login issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671925/pivotal-cloud-foundry-login-issue)

But things did not solved for me yet.

```
$ cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io --skip-ssl-validation
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Email> pxxx.axxx@gmail.com
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.


API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.131.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
FAILED
Unable to authenticate.
```

Here is the

```
$ cf --version
cf.exe version 6.40.0+07673feb9.2018-10-08
```

If I tried to used windows CMD this works very fine. Being windows user I want to make this working using Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be known issue, as only cmd and powershell are supported on windows.
It can be solved one way using `winpty`

```
winpty cf login
```